# Dimension and Cost Center filtering

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++

How can I filter the cost center depending on the selected department and ledger account?

The tree structure has been created and a department has been assigned to the ledger account. In the purchase table, I have selected a particular ledger account and selected the department too, but the Cost center is not getting filtered.

But the same ledger account and department is being used in the Journal-->General Journal 
where as here the cost center gets fileterd.

Can anyone tell me why the cost center is not filtered in purchase table?

Comment: Which version of AX are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to debug the forms `DimensionLookup` and `DimensionSetHierachyLookup`.